# How to calculate comp_ellint_1(0) on a c++11 compiler

Tags: c++11, math, gcc, c++17

I'm sorry if this is a really stupid question, but I really need this for my master thesis, and I just can't find a way. I need to calculate the complete elliptical integral of first kind with eclipse 3.8. on an Ubuntu laptop. My compiler is set to `-c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11`.

As for the ubuntu version, it's

```
@laptop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

and for the gcc compiler, it is

```
laptop:~$ gcc --version 
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I found under [mathematical special functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/special_math) that there is a function [`double comp_ellint_1( float arg )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/special_math/comp_ellint_1) that would do the job, but as I understand it it is only included in C++ 17, which I have not installed and where I can't find information about how to install it. But apparently there is a possibility to calculate the function without C++17? Because it says:

> As all special functions, `comp_ellint_1` is only guaranteed to be available in `<cmath>` if `__STDCPP_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__` is defined by the implementation to a value at least 201003L and if the user defines `__STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__` before including any standard library headers.

But their example code

```
#define __STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__ 1
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>


int main(){

double integral= std::comp_ellint_1(0);
return 0;
}
```

Does not work, the error being *15:22: error: ‘comp_ellint_1’ is not a member of ‘std’*. I've also tried

```
#define _STDCPP_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__201003L
#define __STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__ 1
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

double integral= std::comp_ellint_1(0);
return 0;
}
```

which leads to the same error. It does not say if I need to install certain packages to make it work (if I do need any, which are they and how do I install them). Or am I making a different mistake?

I'd be super thankful for any ideas how to solve this, so thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It's not you who are supposed to define `__STDCPP_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__`, it's the compiler. You define `__STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__` and then *check* `__STDCPP_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__` to make sure the function is available. If not then use *conditional compilation* to write it yourself.

Comment: Also note that GCC 4.8 is *old* and doesn't even support all of C++11. I suggest you upgrade GCC to a later version. Perhaps one which *do* support C++17.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I really need some more help as to do so. So defining __STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS means my prgramm looks like this?

    #define __STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS
    #include <cmath>
    #include <iostream>


    int main(){

    double integral= std::comp_ellint_1(0);
    return 0;
    }

And how do I check __STDCPP_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__? What is conditional compilation?

Comment: I tried also on VS2019 and said: 
Error (active) E0135 namespace "std" has no member "comp_ellint_1" 
. Also happened with ellint_1() and I do not like to have all the large boost library in my laptop

Answer (score 1):

Your gcc 4.8.5 had this function as `std::tr1::comp_ellint_1`. 
You will need to `#include <tr1/cmath>`

This is mentioned in the cppreference page for its C++17 version

Comment: thank you very much, I did not understand this at first, but it worked very well!

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work or want to run on older versions also you can include boost. To do it at Visual Studio you should include:

```
#define BOOST_CONFIG_SUPPRESS_OUTDATED_MESSAGE
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/ellint_1.hpp>  
#include <boost/math/special_functions/ellint_2.hpp>  
#include <boost/math/special_functions/ellint_3.hpp>
```

Then:

```
using namespace boost::math;
double Kk = ellint_1(k);
double Ek1 = ellint_2(k) / (q - 4.*al);
```

To do that you should write a copy of the boost at hard disk, as example at C:\boost_1_66_0

Then by edit the project properties you should add following links:

```
C/C++ Directories->additional include directories: C:\boost_1_66_0
C/C++->Precompiled headers->Precompiled header-> Not use precompiled headers
Linker->general->Additional Library Directories->C:\boost_1_66_0\libs;
```

Another way is to include the following function that calculates both: first and second kind complete integrals. I tested it and worked well using an online tool and the ellint_1 and 2:

```
    void Complete_Elliptic_Integrals(double x, double* Fk, double* Ek)
    {
        const double PI_2 = 1.5707963267948966192313216916397514; // pi/2
        const double PI_4 = 0.7853981633974483096156608458198757; // pi/4
        double k;      // modulus
        double m;      // the parameter of the elliptic function m = modulus^2
        double a;      // arithmetic mean
        double g;      // geometric mean
        double a_old;  // previous arithmetic mean
        double g_old;  // previous geometric mean
        double two_n;  // power of 2
        double sum;

       if ( x == 0.0 ) {       *Fk = M_PI_2;      *Ek = M_PI_2;       return;    }
       k = fabs(x);
       m = k * k;
       if ( m == 1.0 ) {       *Fk = DBL_MAX;      *Ek = 1.0;       return;    }

       a = 1.0;
       g = sqrt(1.0 - m);
       two_n = 1.0;
       sum = 2.0 - m;
       for (int i=0;i<100;i++) 
       {
          g_old = g;
          a_old = a;
          a = 0.5 * (g_old + a_old);
          g = g_old * a_old;
          two_n += two_n;
          sum -= two_n * (a * a - g);
          if ( fabs(a_old - g_old) <= (a_old * DBL_EPSILON) ) break;
          g = sqrt(g);
       } 
       *Fk = (double) (PI_2 / a);
       *Ek = (double) ((PI_4 / a) * sum);
       return;
    }
```

Unfortunately it lasts double than executing ellint_1 and ellint_2